# Does the ediff mode of Emacs support synchronization points?

Tags: emacs, emacs-ediff

I have been using the ediff mode of Emacs for many years now, and I just realized that whenever I need synchronization points (*) to make sense of a diff, I fall back to Meld or KDiff3.

Isn't there some support for synchronization points in ediff? Or is there an alternative diff mode for Emacs supporting this?

(*) A synchronization point allows you to manually align the two sides of a diff at a selected location. The diff is then computed independently for the first and second part of the two sides.

Comment: I digger over the ediff.el and did not find anything like that. There are however functions: ediff-regions-linewise and ediff-regions-wordwise which has similar functionality but are probably not that comfortable as you expected.

Comment: @Vicctor Thanks for pointing out those. Looks like the building blocks for supporting synchronization points are all there, only a good integration into the ediff mode is missing.